# cocoa pods error failed to build gem native extension on Mac

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

```
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r  ./siteconf20200728-45926-1h0nq8i.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/includ.e/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out
```

I'm just trying to install it and it doesn't work.
PS: I also already have cocoa pods. I am simply following the instructions on react native setting up your environment

Comment: If you already have cocoa pods, you can skip that step in the react native setup. That step is only for those who don't have cocoa pods installed already.

Comment: @DougWatkins Then I run into another error when running pod install in the ios folder. I'll add that error later

Comment: any update on what the other error is?

Comment: @DougWatkins solved it by updating repos

Answer (score 0):

The below steps would fix that issue:

1. Ensure ruby is installed and up to date: ruby -v
2. Update gem's sudo gem update --system
3. xcode-select --install
4. sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

Comment: I got this error at step 1: Installing RubyGems 3.1.4
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted @ rb_sysopen - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/gem

Comment: re-ran step 2 and I got no errors but I still get the same error at step 4

Comment: If you are using Mac, Can you try with Homebrew instead of Rubygem, use brew install, it may help

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by updating the repo

`sudo gem repo update`